# Boost: Accessing bimap using operator[]

Tags: c++, boost, bimap

In the following code:

```
typedef bimap< set_of< std::string >, list_of< int > > bm_type;
bm_type bm;

bm.left["one"] = 1; // "one" -> 1
bm.left["one"] = 2; // replaced: "one" -> 2
bm.right[2] = "two"; // Compile error
```

How can I get rid of the compile error? Isn't it possible to access the right view with `operator[]`?

Comment: What are you expecting this to do?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am trying to use bimap like a normal std::map. All my keys and values are unique. I need to be able to get/set keys by values and vice versa. (and I was not sure about using `list_of`)

Comment: But a map has only one place any given element can go. I honestly don't understand what you expect this to do. Can you please describe precisely what `bm.right[2]` should do? For example, if there's no `2` in the list, should it add one? If so, *where*?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I expect `bm.right[2] = "two"` to change "one <-> 2" relation to this: "two <-> 2" (or add this relation if it does not already exist)

Comment: Right, but add it **where**? At the beginning of the list? The end? The middle? Some random place? This just doesn't make sense if the integers are organized as a list.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Does not matter.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be using a list! A list's whole purpose is to preserve arbitrary ordering.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So, will `bimap< set_of< std::string >, set_of< int > >` help?

Comment: Yes, since there is only one way to add an integer to a set of integers.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz But when I change `list_of` to `set_of`, I get compiler error for `bm.left["one"] = 1`.

Comment: Right, because entries in a set are immutable. You need to pick the collection that has precisely the semantics you really want.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Could you please advise on the collections that meet my requirement?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have the same problem. What collection provides a hashmap like behavior?

Answer (score 2):

`list_of` has no `operator[]`.

Look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/reference/list_of_reference.html

Answer (score 1):

This code just doesn't make any sense. [Lists](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) don't have `operator[]` because you have to choose where to insert an element if it's created. Since lists are not internally sorted (like maps are), a `2` can go at the beginning of the list, the end of the list, the middle of the list, or anywhere else.

(Boost's `list_of` mimics the semantics of the standard `list`.)